# Why this AttributeError?

Tags: python-2.7, class, attributeerror

I'm very new to Python and I was trying to use a nice library ([audiotools](https://github.com/tuffy/python-audio-tools)) to play an mp3 playlist, just as an exercise.

This is the class to play the tracklist (loosely based on [THIS](https://github.com/tuffy/python-audio-tools/blob/master/trackplay#L91), once I discovered there is a "callback function with no arguments which is called by the player when the current track is finished" [(*)](https://github.com/tuffy/python-audio-tools/blob/master/audiotools/player.py#L25) ):

```
class Trackplay:
    def __init__(self,
                 track_list,
                 audio_output=audiotools.player.open_output('ALSA'),
                 replay_gain=audiotools.player.RG_NO_REPLAYGAIN):

        self.track_index = INDEX - 1
        self.track_list = track_list

        self.player = audiotools.player.Player(
                audio_output,
                replay_gain,
                self.next_track())

    def next_track(self):
        try:
            self.track_index += 1
            current_track = self.track_list[self.track_index]
            print str(current_track)
            audio_file = audiotools.open(current_track)

            self.player.open(audio_file)   # <---------- error
            self.player.play()
        except IndexError:
            print('playing finished')
```

Then I'm calling:

`tp = Trackplay(get_track_list(PATH))`

where `get_track_list` is a method returning a list of mp3s from the dir `PATH`.

The error I get (at the line marked with the "error" comment) is:

> AttributeError: Trackplay instance has no attribute 'player'

I don't understand what's happening ...but reading all the `AttributeError` questions here, must be something stupid...

`player` seems to me exactly a `Trackplay`'s attribute. Other attributes, as `track_index` and `track_list` seems OK, since the line `print str(current_track)` prints the current track.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is your OS ?

Comment: Tried both on the Rapsberry Pi with Raspbian and the laptop with Linux Mint. Python version is 2.7.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code here?

```
self.player = audiotools.player.Player(
        audio_output,
        replay_gain,
        self.next_track())
```

As part of creating the `Player` you're going to assign to `self.player`, you call `self.next_track()`. `self.next_track` tries to **use `self.player`**, before `self.player` exists!

```
def next_track(self):
    try:
        self.track_index += 1
        current_track = self.track_list[self.track_index]
        print str(current_track)
        audio_file = audiotools.open(current_track)

        self.player.open(audio_file)
        self.player.play()
    except IndexError:
        print('playing finished')
```

`next_track` doesn't even return anything, so it's baffling why you're trying to pass `self.next_track()` as an argument to `Player`.

Was that supposed to be a callback? If so, you should pass `self.next_track` to `Player` **without calling it**.

```
self.player = audiotools.player.Player(
        audio_output,
        replay_gain,
        self.next_track)
#                     ^ no call parentheses
```

Comment: BINGO! I removed the parentheses and then called a `self.next_track()` with the parentheses (as a method) afterwards and it works... One song after the other... thank you sooo much. I understand what you say about the calling before the `player` even exists... now it's clear... I said it in the Q, noob error  -  well, actually two: the parentheses for the callback and the call before assignment  -  COOL.   :)